# Proper Error Handling in Ruby

Tags: ruby, error-handling, nokogiri

I have a block of code that looks like this:

```
def create_page_object(url)
  begin
    page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  rescue
    puts "page not loaded"
  end
end
```

and then I call it via:

```
result.each do |url|
  page = create_page_object(url)
  content = make_content(page)
end
```

Now, in the terminal I see "page not loaded" and then Ruby blows up on me. How can I say, "If page not loaded, stop and go to the next each item".

***Update:***

A Scientific Definition of Blowing Up:

```
test.rb:70:in `get_title': undefined method `xpath' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from test.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in process'
    from test.rb:35:in `each'
    from test.rb:35:in `block in process'
    from test.rb:32:in `upto'
    from test.rb:32:in `process'
    from test.rb:138:in `<main>'
```

What I believe is happening is because the is not being loaded, it there is no page variable set, which is nil and being throw into the make_content function.

Comment: You get an error because create_page_object returns nil. create_page_object returns nil because this is the value of the latest expression in the method execution ('puts' method returns nil).

Comment: Right Alex, but my question was more how do I handle it. I've never seen the `next` method before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rescue block is returning the output of `puts` (which is `nil`), you have to make sure you have a document before working with it. Note also that in the rescue you should explicitly return `nil` to make clear what is the method returning in that branch. I'd write:

```
def create_page_object(url)
  begin
    page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  rescue
    puts "page not loaded"
    nil
  end
end

result.each do |url|
  if (page = create_page_object(url))
    content = make_content(page)
  end
end
```

I don't know your especific needs, but it's usually a bad idea to do "pre-emptive" rescues. Rescue when you have something useful to do, otherwise you're preventing higher levels to do so.

Comment: Is the if conditional idiomatic ruby?

Comment: @NoahClark. Good question. I am sure some people don't like it, but personally I do (even coming from Python were that would be heresy). Surrounded by parenthesis it's compact, safe and clear. Note that in Ruby "everything" returns an expression, even an assignment statement.

Comment: @NoahClark: I do it all the time but I'm also prefer heresy over dogma :)

Comment: @muistooshort And for that you must burn!

Comment: Actually there is no need to manually return `nil`.  Ruby will return `nil` if it doesn't find something else to return.  The only reason your code is working and his was not is because the `if` statement that you put to check to ensure that the page object existed.

Comment: @Batkins. Not exactly: in the rescue he was returning the output of `puts`, which incidentally happens to be nil. I think it's better to be explicit.

Comment: @tokland.  Makes sense, I suppose you are right about that.  My point was that the reason he was having the error is because he was trying to make a call for a method on a `nil` object, and that should be the emphasis for your solution.  It seemed like your solution was more focused on setting the content of the return (which was being set to nil anyways) than the actual solution (the `if` statement checking to ensure the object was set before making the call on it).

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways to deal with this so here's another:

```
def create_page_object(url)
  begin
    page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
    yield page
  rescue
    puts "page not loaded"
  end
end

result.each do |url|
  create_page_object(url) { |page| content = make_content(page) }
end
```

But if you need the `content` outside the block:

```
content =  nil
result.each do |url|
  create_page_object(url) { |page| content = make_content(page) }
end
```

Or you might be able to put more `content` handling logic inside the block:

```
result.each do |url|
  create_page_object(url) do |page|
    content = make_content(page)
    # do interesting things with 'content' here
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't usually like methods that force you to use blocks without a good reason, but in any case this is very instructive: it's an example of "maybe" pattern using blocks.

Comment: @tokland: I don't like being forced to do much of anything :) But, when properly used they can simplify your program flow by pushing the "if/else for the uncommon cases" around. This answer is mostly a "here's another option that may or may not make sense in your specific situation" thing; people seem to forget that they can write their own methods that work with blocks just like they forget that they can write helper classes instead of mashing Hashes and Arrays through a big mess of Enumerable methods.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this would be to return nil in the create_page_object(url) if you had to rescue it and return true if it is loaded in Nokogiri::HTML(open(url)). That way you can test if it is nil and just next through the loop if that is the case. Example:

```
def create_page_object(url)
  begin
    page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  rescue
    puts "page not loaded"
    return nil
  end
end
```

and

```
result.each do |url|
  page = create_page_object(url)
  next if page.nil?
  content = make_content(page)
end
```

I am surprised that "Nokogiri" throws an exception if the page isn't loaded rather than returning a nil object, but if that is how it works, then this method should do it for you. Good luck.

Comment: You need to take out the `return true` because make_content expects a nokogiri object. Other than that it works great! Thanks!

Comment: also: 1) writing "return" is not idiomatic. 2) more idiomatic: `next unless page`

Comment: @tokland, I agree on the return. But is there an argument to be made that `next if page.nil?` is more explicit or clear? It could be that the `next unless page` is just new to me and so it looks unfamiliar.

Comment: Making explicit tests may look "better" at first, but you'll see that nothing is more clear than using the truthness/falsehood of the objects themselves (in Ruby it's easy: everything is true except for nil and false). You don't write `if a == true`, you write `if a`. Same here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def create_page_object(url)
  begin
    Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  rescue
    puts "page not loaded"
  end
end

result.each do |url|
  page = create_page_object(url)
  next if page.nil?
  content = make_content(page)
end
```

In Ruby, the last expression in method is the returned value, so that you can omit your assignment. `puts` method isn't return anything and you get `nil` in case of throwing exception.

Comment: mmm, I'd really write an explicit `nil`, you're making a completely unrelated method (`puts`) to return it for you, that may be confusing. Also, isn't `next unless page` more idiomatic? you only use `obj.nil?` if you want to tell false from nil.

Comment: Yeah, agree with you. and also your `next unless page` is definitely looks better.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using "rescue OpenURI::HTTPError => e" instead of just "rescue".